# Having issues in using the Oracle Rank function

Tags: oracle

I have table `call_detail` with following columns `phone_no`, `call_id`, `call_date`. I want to create a view with every row and the previous made call from each record. How can I achieve that?

I have tried using rank with a self join on the table `call_detail` but that gives me only the latest record from the table.

Comment: use LAG analytical function.

Comment: LAG will not work here as it will give me the exact previous date entry without taking the phone no in consideration.

Comment: LAG will not work here as it will give me the exact previous date entry without taking the phone no in consideration.            phone_no    call_id     call_date
234543453   1         1-12-2013 8:11:03 PM
234556777   2         1-11-2013 8:11:03 PM
234543453   3         1-12-2013 6:11:03 PM
234534534   4         1-11-2013 8:11:03 PM
234543453   5         1-12-2013 4:11:03 PM
234534534   6         1-11-2013 8:11:03 PM
234543453   7         1-12-2013 3:11:03 PM
 Now if i want to get previous call id for a phone no and current call id also will LAG work here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing with `lag()` but it doesn't sound right. It sounds like exactly what you're after; [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions082.htm):

> `LAG` is an analytic function. It provides access to more than one row of a table at the same time without a self join.

You want the previous call for each phone number, so you need to partition by `phone_no`, and order by `call_date`. This shows the previous value for all three fields:

```
select phone_no, call_id, call_date,
  lag(phone_no) over (partition by phone_no order by call_date)
    as prev_phone_no,
  lag(call_id) over (partition by phone_no order by call_date)
    as prev_call_id,
  lag(call_date) over (partition by phone_no order by call_date)
    as prev_call_date
from call_detail
order by call_date;
```

With the sample data you gave in a comment this gives:

```
PHONE_NO          CALL_ID CALL_DATE           PREV_PHONE_NO  PREV_CALL_ID PREV_CALL_DATE    
-------------- ---------- ------------------- -------------- ------------ -------------------
234534534               4 2013-01-11 20:11:03                                                 
234534534               6 2013-01-11 20:11:03 234534534                 4 2013-01-11 20:11:03 
234556777               2 2013-01-11 20:11:03                                                 
234543453               7 2013-01-12 15:11:03                                                 
234543453               5 2013-01-12 16:11:03 234543453                 7 2013-01-12 15:11:03 
234543453               3 2013-01-12 18:11:03 234543453                 5 2013-01-12 16:11:03 
234543453               1 2013-01-12 20:11:03 234543453                 3 2013-01-12 18:11:03
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ab1d/1)

Which you can use to create a view (without an `order by` clause, and with only the columns you want).